# Describing subfields of $\mathbb{Z}_2(t)$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I am studying Galois Theory and found this exercise:

> Describe this subfield of $\mathbb{Z}_2(t): \ \mathbb{Z}_2(t^2)$

The definition of $K(t)$, where $K$ is a field, that I'm using is:

> $K(t)=\{\frac{p(t)}{q(t)}: p(t),q(t) \in K[t] \textrm{ and } q\neq 0\}$

So using this definition the only thing I got is that every element of $\mathbb{Z_2}(t)$ it's like this:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\alpha_it^{2i}+\beta_i}{\gamma_it^{2i}+\delta_i}\textrm{, where }\alpha_i,\beta_i,\gamma_i,\delta_i  \in \mathbb{Z_2} \textrm{ and } \gamma_it^{2i}+\delta_i\neq 0 \  $$
 But I don't feel it's correct because it's just the definition nothing more.

There's more thing to do ?

Comment: Observe that in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ you have that $1=1^2$ and $0=0^2$. In $\mathbb{Z}_2(t)$ you also have $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2$. Therefore $g(t^2)$ with $g\in\mathbb{Z}_2[t]$ can be written as $g(t^2)=g(t)^2$. Therefore the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2(t^2)$ are the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2(t)$ that are squares.

Comment: I suspect you are just being asked to say something like it's the subfield comprising the rational functions of $t^2$. As an aside: your definition looks wrong: $\Bbb{Z}_2$ should probably read $K$ and the condition should be $q \neq 0$ not $q(t) \neq 0 \forall t$. (Something like  $1/(t^2-t)$ is a perfectly good member of $\Bbb{Z}_2(t)$ even though $t^2-t$ evaluates to $0$ for $t \in \Bbb{Z}_2$.)

Comment: Oh, I missed that. I'll correct

Comment: I wonder if you are going to need to find the degree of the field extension. If you do, remember that $\frac{p(t)}{q(t)}=\frac{q(t)p(t)}{q(t)^2}=\frac{q(t)p(t)}{q(t^2)}$ and that any polynomial $h(t)$ can be written as $1\cdot h_1(t^2)+t\cdot h_2(t^2)$

Comment: @SphericalTriangle, everything you say is true, but $k(t)\supset k(t^2)$ is still a quadratic extension, having nothing to do with $k=\Bbb F_2$, or even perfectness of $k$.

Comment: @Lubin It is faster for me to write the identity above, which is enough in this problem, than having to write $\frac{p(t)}{q(t)}=\frac{p_0(t^2)+tp_1(t^2)}{q_0(t^2)+tq_1(t^2)}=\frac{(q_0(t^2)-tq_1(t^2))(p_0(t^2)+tp_1(t^2))}{q_0^2(t^2)-t^2q_1(t^2)}$

Comment: Indeed, @SphericalTriangle, your method was precisely what occurred to me first. But I decided to dislike it because it depended on special properties of the base field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description of elements of $\Bbb F_2(t)$ is not on the mark. A typical element of this field looks like
$$
\frac{a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2+\cdots a_mt^m}{b_0+b_1t+b_2t^2+\cdots b_nt^n}\,,
$$
with not all of the $b_j$ being zero.

The typical element of $\Bbb F_2(t^2)$ is same, but with all exponents being even.

I’m sure they wanted you to recognize that the big field is quadratic over the smaller field.